# How to create an ordered/numbered list in javascript without html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a music bot for Discord and I seem to have stumbled in to a problem with the music queue. Whenever I want to see the queue, the songs are presented with a `-` before the name. I wish for the songs to be automatically numbered.

I have looked everywhere, including videos on youtube and tutorials. I still have no idea how to do it.

```js
const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
if (!serverQueue) 
  return message.channel.send(embed1);

const embedq = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle(`**Now playing:** ${serverQueue.songs[0].title}`)
  .setDescription(`${serverQueue.songs.map(song => `${song.title}`).join('\n')}`)
```

I expect the output of the queue to look like this:

```
1) Joyner Lucas ft. Logic - ISIS
2) KSHMR x KAAZE - Devil Inside Me
```

However the actual output is

```
- Joyner Lucas ft. Logic - ISIS
```

Comment: Is `(song, i) => \`${i+1}) ${song.title}\`` instead of `song => \`${song.title}\`` what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index of your `.map` iteration to add the numbers.

```
.setDescription(`
    ${serverQueue.songs.map((song, index) => `${index+1}) ${song.title}`).join('\n')}
`)
```